# What was the best selling TSR Dungeons & Dragons module?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

As the title says, I want to know what was the best selling TSR [Dungeons & Dragons module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_modules) - no matter for what D&D edition - before  Wizards of the Coast acquired TSR in 1997.

I suspect it was [I6: Ravenloft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenloft_(module)), by Tracy & Laura Hickman, published by TSR in 1983, but it's only an (un)educated guess, I have no proof of this.

Comment: Actual sales figures are notoriously slippery, obfuscated by the purpose behind releasing them, and sometimes further obscured—accidentally or purposefully—by the number of units *shipped* or *produced* (rather than sold). I bring this up because I seriously look forward to *any* answer that can cite an authoritative source for treeware *units sold* (However, I don't look forward to a barrage of questions like this… despite being mildly interested in how well [*Sages and Specialists*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sages_%26_Specialists) sold.)

Comment: Are you *only* accepting answers from the list you link? I ask because I strongly suspect that something like *Sunless Citadel* or *Keep on the Shadowfell* or *Lost Mine of Phandelver* would be in the running if it's not just what's listed on that page.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because its can only ever be accurate for a given point in time, which unfortunately refuses to stop passing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I do think that this is a question that doesn't exactly fit SE since it doesn't seem to solve a specific problem about RPG, but well, we have History of Gaming tag. Most of these seem to be more about curiosity than solving a problem, being fair.

Comment: I think the general concept is fine, but I feel it is likely to be unanswerable due to public unavailability of sales figures, definitions of "a module", and what constitutes a "sale". (Does a large adventure published in Dragon Magazine count? How about overseas sales? AL modules?)

Comment: @keithcurtis Being unanswerable is not a reason to close, though, and surely doesn't make it off-topic. You could argue that, as it is, it's unclear (as you mention, what's a module and what's a sale), but that aside I don't see how it's off-topic.

Comment: While not a reason to close, this is only answerable by an insider or researcher that (still) has access to the original sales figures - which might be lost or earlier years. I know I found that many documents older than 10 years have been destroyed or archived off site when I was allowed to research the history of a company once.

Comment: @HellSaint I did not recommend closing or call it off-topic.

Comment: This looks like a well-defined question to me now, with a time frame that allows for a (potentially knowable) answer that isn’t a moving target. “Module” and “sale” don’t seem ambiguous — modules are modules, and in normal usage “best selling” means original sale by publisher, so that seems fine to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A strong candidate seems to be [B2: The Keep on the Borderlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keep_on_the_Borderlands), by Gary Gygax, first published in December 1979.

Wikipedia says:

> Lawrence Schick, in his 1991 book *Heroic Worlds*, describes the
>   adventure as "A good start for new players" and speculates that at the
>   time, there had probably been more copies of B2 printed than of any
>   other role-playing scenario.

Looking for the exact quote, I found this Google site called [Zenopus Archives](https://sites.google.com/site/zenopusarchives/home/modules-and-scenarios/b2-keep-on-the-borderlands):

> "There probably have been more copies of B2 printed than any other
>   role-playing scenario" - Heroic Worlds by Lawrence Shick, 1991 (pg
>   135).
>
> "The total print run for B2 is easily in excess of a million and a
>   half units" - "Looking Back" by Ryan Dancey in The Story of TSR, 1999
>   (pg 27).

[The Acaeum](https://www.acaeum.com/index.html) website, which I didn't know until today, but seems to be [a reference for Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=acaeum&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=9uqq01ehkrwehxaiy6sycedzv), has a [Print Run Estimates](https://www.acaeum.com/library/printrun.html) page about D&D products, which again puts *B2: The Keep on the Borderlands* on top, with two runners-up:

> **B2 Keep on the Borderlands:** 1,000,000+. *Source: 1999 Silver
>   Anniversary Retrospective booklet*
>
> **S1 Tomb of Horrors:** 250,000+. *Source: Gary Gygax verbal comment*
>
> **S2 White Plume Mountain:** 175,000+. *Source: WotC employee*

There's still the problem of comparing print runs with total sales, specially in the case of *B2: The Keep on the Borderlands* because - although the module was still sold separately - it was included in the [Dungeons & Dragons Basic Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_Basic_Set) from 1979 to 1982, just before the famous [1983 Red Box edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_Basic_Set#1983_revision).